# Need help in mapping fields with Plugin: "Forms: 3rd-Party Integration"

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to connect contact form 7 with velocify using the Plugin: **"Forms: 3rd-Party Integration"**. Lead created in velocify but no field data import. I have mapped the fields correctly as per the instructions given. Here is the debug message:

**SUBMISSION**

```
Array
    (
        [timeout] => 60
        [body] =>
    )
```

**RAW RESPONSE**

```
Array
(
    [reason] => Could not locate success clause within response
    [safe_message] => Success Clause not found
    [clause] => done
    [response] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ImportResults><ImportResult refId="" leadId="0" result="Failure" message="No input data was found" /></ImportResults>
)
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange place to ask this question, as opposed to:

- [WP stack exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)
- [the plugin support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/forms-3rdparty-integration)
- [the plugin Github issue tracker](https://github.com/zaus/forms-3rdparty-integration/issues)

That said, as the plugin author I suggest you read the support forum's sticky post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/its-not-sending-data-help-read-this-first/

Specifically in your case, the debug email tells you the two problems:

1. You've configured the service to expect the word 'done' in the response, and it's not finding it
2. It's not finding it because, as the response indicates 'No input data was found' confirming the empty body of the submission.

The second issue (which is the real problem) is probably that you're not mapping it correctly.  But without the full debug (or at least the service configuration section of it) I can't tell you why.  Look at the "Post (Form)" section to see what's available to map.  If you have done it all correctly it may be a compatibility issue -- make sure you're using the latest versions of all relevant plugins, try turning off other unrelated plugins to see if there's some kind of conflict, and finally if you have FTP access turn on WP_DEBUG mode and check the log file.